# Deleting VMware image does not free up hard disk space

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I recently found out that I am low on hard disk space and am unable to allocate new hard disk space for my virtual machines. Upon realising this, I proceeded to delete a few of my virtual machines images which I no longer used , I even deleted the entire folder.

By right this should free up the hard disk space but the problem now is that is does not.

How do i reclaim all the hard disk space which I have lost

How i delete from disk 
[image: How I delete from disk]

How I remove from folder

[image]

My system capacity (hard disk space) does not change

[image]

Comment: Did you empty the Wastebasket?

Comment: @afh wastebasket ?? I emptied my windows recycle bin

Comment: I thought you were on Ubuntu. I guess you need to do a disc check. Unless you accidentally moved your VM files to another (possibly hidden)  directory, the deletion must have failed to release the disc used to the free space.